# Javascript: finding the number of times a value occurs in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I'd like to excuse myself in case this is a stupid question, but i can't figure out what is going wrong here. I am fairly new to d3 and to be honest Javascript as a whole. I have a json file which looks like this:

```
[{"plaats":"AMSTERDAM","geboortejaar":1990,"vooropleiding":"MBO"}, {"plaats":"GENK","geboortejaar":1987,"vooropleiding":"HAVO"}, {"plaats":"JOPPE","geboortejaar":1992,"vooropleiding":"VWO"}]
```

I am trying to figure out how often the values "HAVO", "MBO" and "VWO" occur in my JSON file. To do so, I wrote the following code:

```
var svgHeight = 400;
var svgWidth = 400;

var svg = d3.select("#pieChart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", svgHeight)
    .attr("width", svgWidth);

d3.json("propedeuse.json", function (error, json) {

    alert("Hello, " + json[2]);

    var VWO = 0,
        HAVO = 0,
        MBO = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= json.length; i++) { 

        if (json[i].vooropleiding == "VWO") {
            VWO++; 
        }

        else if (json[i].vooropleiding == "HAVO") {
            HAVO++;
        }

        else {
            MBO++;
        }
    }

    svg.append("p")
    .text(HAVO);

    console.log("MBO: " + HAVO);
    console.log("HAVO: " + HAVO);
    console.log("VWO: " + VWO);

    });
```

I do get the alert, "Hello, [object Object]". But according to my console json[i] is undefined. How come it is suddenly undefined, while it's working perfectly fine with the alert?

What i need to happen (in this example) is for the console to log 1 for each value.

Comment: Your example and code above can't be complete/correct. There are only 3 elements in the array, so `json[16]` is undefined. The alert should say "Hello, undefined". Without seeing the actual data, it's only a guess, but perhaps is one of your array elements missing the property `vooropleiding` (or has it misspelled)?

Comment: @StephenThomas That's my bad, the actual json file i am using has 282 elements in the array, i just used three for the example now. Thanks for letting me know, i edit it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jL2We/1/

```
var data = [{"plaats":"AMSTERDAM","geboortejaar":1990,"vooropleiding":"MBO"}, {"plaats":"GENK","geboortejaar":1987,"vooropleiding":"HAVO"}, {"plaats":"JOPPE","geboortejaar":1992,"vooropleiding":"VWO"}];

// Inside d3.json, your "json" variable is equivalent to this "data"

var vwo = data.filter(function(d) { return d.vooropleiding === "VWO"; }).length,
    havo = data.filter(function(d) { return d.vooropleiding === "HAVO"; }).length,
    mbo = data.filter(function(d) { return d.vooropleiding === "MBO"; }).length;

document.getElementById("vwo").innerText = vwo;
document.getElementById("havo").innerText = havo;
document.getElementById("mbo").innerText = mbo;
```

I agree with @Jonah. This is just a JavaScript question. Here's another way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was sort hoping there'd be a filter sort of function, i just didn't expected it to be called that way. But yeah, this helped me a lot.

Comment: It's standard in ECMAScript 5, which means [be careful in IE < 9](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). There's a `jQuery.grep` function that does the same thing that extends functionality for those older browsers, or use an [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Comment: Also, you already know how to turn the JSON source into an array (D3 does that for you in your case), so you might get a lot more views/upvotes if you change your question title to something like "How to find number of times value occurs in array of objects" or something. Gotta get those internet points!

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't appear to be about d3.  It's really just a javascript question.  This will return an object with the desired counts:

```
var json = [{"plaats":"AMSTERDAM","geboortejaar":1990,"vooropleiding":"MBO"}, {"plaats":"GENK","geboortejaar":1987,"vooropleiding":"HAVO"}, {"plaats":"JOPPE","geboortejaar":1992,"vooropleiding":"VWO"}];

var answer = json.reduce(function(prev, cur) {  
    var val = cur["vooropleiding"];
    prev[val] = (prev[val] || 0) + 1;
    return prev;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.